# How to hide bootstrap offcanvas in vue3 when router-link is clicked?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, hide, bootstrap-5

Good day, I would like to hide bootstrap-5/Offcanvas when I click on link inside. Here is Offcanvas:

```
  //Button activate Offcanvas
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvasDarkNavbar"
          aria-controls="offcanvasDarkNavbar">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  //Offcanvas
  <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end text-bg-dark" tabindex="-1" id="offcanvasDarkNavbar"
       aria-labelledby="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">
    <div class="offcanvas-header">
      <h5 class="offcanvas-title" id="offcanvasDarkNavbarLabel">Menu</h5>
    </div>
    <div class="offcanvas-body">
      <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-sm-auto mb-0 align-items-center align-items-sm-start" id="menu">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <router-link to="/about" class="nav-link link-info align-middle px-0">
            <i class="fs-4 bi-house"></i> <span class="ms-1 d-none d-sm-inline">Home</span>
          </router-link>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
```

In official docs they say:

> You can create an offcanvas instance with the constructor, for example:
> var myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('myOffcanvas') OR
> var bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas)

and then use method "hide". I tried to use in router-link @click="hideThisCanvas" and then

```
methods: {
  hideThisCanvas(){
    let myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasDarkNavbar')
    myOffcanvas.hide();
  }
}
```

but it gives the error `myOffcanvas.hide is not a function`. Please, help!

Comment: The best approach is probably to use something state-based like bootstrap-vue: https://bootstrap-vue.org/ Using document selectors is not the way to go in any modern JS framework tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to create an offcanvas instance with the constructor, for example:

```
methods: {
  hideThisCanvas(){
    let myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasDarkNavbar')
    let bsOffcanvas = bootstrap.Offcanvas.getInstance(myOffcanvas);
    bsOffcanvas.hide();
  }
}
```

OR

```
methods: {
      hideThisCanvas(){
        let myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasDarkNavbar')
        let bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas);
        bsOffcanvas.hide();
      }
    }
```

Because using traditional document selectors is not ideal for modern JS framework, you can create a ref for your offCanvas like this.

```
<div ref="offCanvas" class="offcanvas offcanvas-start" tabindex="-1" id="example_canvas">
```

Then access it in your vuejs function the way you should

**example**

```
let myOffcanvas = this.$refs.offCanvas;
```

your final method should be something like this

```
methods: {
      hideThisCanvas(){
        let myOffcanvas = this.$refs.offCanvas;
        let bsOffcanvas = new bootstrap.Offcanvas(myOffcanvas);
        bsOffcanvas.hide();
      }
    }
```

I  do not know so much about vuejs but I hope you get concept now and it helps you.

Comment: Don't use query selectors in a state-based framework.

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH, IT WORKS. TOTALLY:

import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap"

export default {
  name: "MyNavbar",
  methods: {
    hideThisCanvas(){
      let myOffcanvas = document.getElementById('offcanvasDarkNavbar')
      let bsOffcanvas = bootstrap.Offcanvas.getInstance(myOffcanvas);
      bsOffcanvas.hide();
    }
  }
}
</script>

Comment: @kissu I agree with you, Using document selectors is not ideal in any modern JS framework, if it was Reactjs I'd use the useRef hook but this is vuejs I assume he knows how to go about it. I don't know so much in vuejs

Comment: You do have `useRef` in React, you do you have `$ref` in Vue with the same purpose. No reason to use anything else here, for the exact same reason.

Comment: @kissu I have updated my answer to how its supposed to be in Vue

Comment: You can even put it at the beginning of your answer, since it's the proper way of doing things. :D

Answer (score 0):

"Clicking" toggler works as well. Create function that your router-links calls via @click:

```
function closeOffcanvas() {
   document.getElementById('offcanvasToggler').click()
}
```

Toggler must have id:

```
<button id="offcanvasToggler" class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-target="#offcanvas" aria-controls="offcanvas">
```

And router just calls function to evoke click:

```
<router-link :to="{ name: 'home'}" class="nav-link" @click.prevent="closeOffcanvas()">
```

I'm sure a nicer vue-like code using ref as mentioned above exists. This one works for me as is.
You can also reference close button if you have it, the one with

```
data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas"
```